# Excel 2013 DDE function

Tags: microsoft-excel, dde

I have a problem with the DDE function in Excel 2013.

When I try to use **=DDE(X, y, Z)** the function does not appear in Excel.

I know that maybe it is a stupid question but after an hour I can't find anything I started to suspect that the function is not supported anymore.

Do you know if I have to install an additional addin or something or simply this function is not supported anymore by Excel?

**UPDATE**

There is not DDE Function in Excel but you can read from a DDE server with the following format

**=Service|Topic!Item**

That is the way to read from a DDE Server in Excel

Answer (score 1):

Excel does not have a DDE() function and it never had. Microsoft will keep functions in Excel for backwards compatibility forever.  If you have used such a function in the past it must have been part of a 3rd party add-in.

Access, however, does have a DDE function.

You don't explain what that function is supposed to be doing. It would help to know what you are trying to achieve.

Comment: I added an update to my question.  You were right there is not DDE Function in Excel but there was a way to read from a DDE source.